# Switching to modules mode Vuex.Store in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm finding solution to swich to module mode for Vuex Store in VueJS. Because I use NuxtJS so the default store will be in classic mode.

I follow this instruction: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#modules-mode but It's not work.

Hope your guy helps me!

**~/store/index.js**

```
export const AuthenticationStore = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      authUser: null,
      userInfo: null,
      token: null
    },
    mutations: {
      SET_USER: function (state, user) {
        state.authUser = user
      },
      SET_TOKEN: function (state, token) {
        state.token = token
        instance.defaults.headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token }
      }
    },
    actions: {
      async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
        try {
          const jwtCookie = req.headers.cookie.split(';').find(c => c.trim().startsWith('token='))
          if (jwtCookie) {
            let token = jwtCookie.split('=')[1]
            let payload = jwtDecode(token)
            let date = Date.now() / 1000
            if (payload.exp > date) {
              commit('SET_USER', payload)
              commit('SET_TOKEN', token)
              instance.defaults.baseURL = backendURL
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('nuxtServerInit Failed')
        }
      },
      async login ({ commit }, { username, password }) {
        try {
          const { data } = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/api-token-auth/login', {
            username,
            password
          })
          let payload = jwtDecode(data.token)
          Cookie.set('token', data.token, {
            expires: null
          })
          commit('SET_TOKEN', data.token)
          commit('SET_USER', payload)
        } catch (error) {}
      },
      async logout ({ commit }) {
        Cookie.remove('token')
        commit('SET_USER', null)
        commit('SET_TOKEN', null)
        window.location.href = '/'
      }
    },
    modules: {
      ...
    }
  })
```

Error:

`[vuex] unknown action type: login` when dispatch action in components:

```
async login () {
      try {
        await this.$store.dispatch('login', {
          username: this.signupUsername,
          password: this.signupPassword
        })
        this.signupUsername = ''
        this.signupPassword = ''
      } catch (e) {}
    }
```

I want to switch to modules with write `export const store` in order to import const store into other js file in my project.

Comment: What have you tried? Why it's not working? What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: Fixed it. Anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using modular approach, you will need to add,`{ root : true}` to access root actions, mutations, getters etc. Like :

> $store.dispatch('login', { username: this.signupUsername, password:
>   this.signupPassword }, { root : true} )

`

Comment: Also get error `node_modules\vuex\dist\vuex.esm.js:417 [vuex] unknown action type: login`

Comment: Fixed it. Anyway. Thanks!

Comment: No, my Vuex have some problems and I fixed it anyway :)

Comment: This is my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48658369/cant-get-state-stored-by-vuex-in-plugins-axios-js