# Can't get state stored by Vuex in ~/plugins/axios.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I have problem to get token stored by Vuex in ~/plugins/axios.js. Hope your guys take a look for me please.

My Vuex: ~/store/index.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  authUser: null,
  token: null
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_USER: function (state, user) {
    state.authUser = user
  },
  SET_TOKEN: function (state, token) {
    state.token = token
    instance.defaults.headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token }
  }
}

export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    ...
  },
  async login ({ commit }, { username, password }) {
    ...
  }
}

const store = () => new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  modules: {
    feed,
    users,
    notification,
    messenger
  }
})

export default store

const VuexStore = () => {
  return store
}
export { VuexStore }
```

**~/plugins/axios**, which `VuexStore.state` is not data!

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {VuexStore} from '~/store'

var api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/'
})
console.log(VuexStore.state.token) // Null data

export default api
```

Console log is:

```
ƒ VuexStore() {
  return store;
}
```

Comment: Try ```import {store} from './store'``` and store.state.token.

Comment: `"export 'store' was not found in '~/store'`. It comes to error, bro!!

Comment: No. I have all 3 lines in my store/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you could use something like:

## ~/store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const state = () => ({
  authUser: null,
  token: null
})

const mutations = {
  SET_USER: function (state, user) {
    state.authUser = user
  },
  SET_TOKEN: function (state, token) {
    state.token = token
    instance.defaults.headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token }
  }
}

const getters = {
 ...
}

const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    ...
  },
  async login ({ commit }, { username, password }) {
    ...
  }
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters,
  modules: {
    ...
  }
});
```

## ~/plugins/axios.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import VuexStore from '~/store'

var api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/'
})
console.log(VuexStore.state.token) 

export default api
```

Comment: I got error when fix like you type: `[nuxt] store/index.js should export a method which returns a Vuex instance.`